# Selecting multiple listbox items to set a filter

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I'm trying to select a YEAR and TYPE of business (1 or more) and then autofilter a column. That way I can use only 1 macro instead of making many for all the alternatives.

[(Year Select)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo7rc.jpg)

[(Type of Business)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzP6W.jpg)

This is what I have at the moment:

```
Private Sub Botton1_Click()
Public Platform As String
Public Year as Integer
Platform = UserForm1.LB2.Text
Year = UserForm1.LB1.value
Unload UserForm1


End Sub
```

......

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With LB1

.AddItem "2016"
.AddItem "2017"
.AddItem "2018"

End With

With LB2

.AddItem "CMP"
.AddItem "AS"
.AddItem "MasterBread"
.AddItem "CMI -Andino"
.AddItem "CMI -Brasil"
.AddItem "CMI -CAMEC"
.AddItem "CMI -ConoSur"
.AddItem "Global"
End With

End Sub
```

The year will always be only 1 value but business type can be 1 or more.

How do I store multiple values of the listbox in order to call the variable as a filter?

This is were I need to call the variables:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$1500").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="2016"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$1500").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=AS", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=MASTER BREAD"
```

In this example I needed to filter "2016" and "AS & MASTER BREAD".

Comment: [This](http://mariaevert.dk/vba/?p=140) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented code that your button should use, based on what you've provided in your question:

```
Private Sub Botton1_Click()

    Dim rData As Range
    Dim sFilters As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set rData = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$1500")
    rData.AutoFilter    'Remove any existing filters

    'Get the selected year
    If LB1.ListIndex > -1 Then
        'Filter the year
        rData.AutoFilter 4, LB1.Text
    End If

    'Gather all selected values in LB2 (type of business)
    For i = 0 To LB2.ListCount - 1
        'If value is selected, add to sFilters variable
        If LB2.Selected(i) Then sFilters = sFilters & "|" & LB2.List(i)
    Next i

    If Len(sFilters) > 0 Then
        'Filter on selected values
        rData.AutoFilter 2, Split(sFilters, "|"), xlFilterValues
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly I just needed to add the unload Userform1 at the end so the macro could continue running! Thanks !