# How to take in multiple values as user input using SQL in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, input

I have a table in access database with a column "Code" that has about 500 types of codes. For instance, "UZD", "LOT", "XUQ". I have built this query to take in user input of a particular code and then retrieve all data for that code.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Code = [Enter Code]
```

And this works well for just one code as user input. Problem is, how do I make this work for multiple inputs?

If a user has to query 3 codes. say, code "UZD", "LOT" and "XUQ". How should I build the query to handle that?

This is what I am trying but it wont retrieve any results. Just returns blank data. And I know I have the codes in my data.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Code in ([Enter Codes separated by comma])
```

Any suggestions, much appreciated.

Comment: `WHERE column in ([Single parameter, values separated by comma])` -- unfortunately this doesn't work. It sure would make some things easier. You will need VBA to build the query dynamically, or a temp table to join with your table.

Comment: The array list for IN() cannot be dynamic in query object. Must use VBA to build. Common approach is to use a multi-select listbox and loop through selected items. Then apply filter criteria to form or report. Fairly common topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting multiple listbox items to set a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403367/selecting-multiple-listbox-items-to-set-a-filter)